# Combine methods (using prototype property) that already have their own properties

Tags: javascript, prototype

i have 2 objects, **human** and **sam**, with 2 given properties each

```
var human = {
  legs: 2,
  group: "mammal"
}
var sam = {
  age: 23,
  married: true
}
```

*Can I attach the **human** object to the prototype of **sam** so that the properties of **human** are delegated to **sam**, and the **sam** object remains intact.*
The desired result: 
`console.log(sam.legs); //=> 2`

One way i am aware of (but i know is "bad practice") is to use the `__proto__`  property:

```
var sam = { 
  age: 23,
  married: true,
  __proto__: human  // *NOT IDEAL*
}
```

*or*

```
sam.__proto__ = human;  // *NOT IDEAL*
```

I am aware of `Object.create()` but i do not know how to implement it without erasing everything that is already stored in the **sam** variable

```
var human = {
  legs: 2,
  group: "mammal"
}
var sam = {
  age: 23,
  married: true
}

sam = Object.create(human);

console.log(sam.age);   //=> undefined
```

I know that I can just attach the **human** object to **sam** FIRST, and THEN assign properties to **sam**:

```
var human = {
  legs: 2,
  group: "mammal"
}

var sam = Object.create(human);

sam.age = 23;
married: true;
```

...but the whole point of my question is if i attach two objects, using the prototype property, that already have their own properties? Can i use Object.create() in a way that I'm not aware of?

*I must have read everything on the first page of google results for `object.create()` and i never saw the right type of examples*

EDIT: I don't want to just copy properties over because i am working on a game and i don't want the changes to be permanent. Let's say that `sam` has the `human` prototype, but at any minute in the game, his prototype could change to `zombie` or whatever.

Comment: This is about prototypes, but it doesn't seem to be about Prototype.js, the framework. Did you really mean to include that tag?

Comment: The usual javascript way to do this would be to just copy the properties of `human` to `sam` so `sam` becomes a combined object with the union of properties.  Perhaps you should describe what problem you have that makes the usual way of doing this not applicable.  `.__proto__` is deprecated.  There is an experimental `.setPrototypeOf()`, but it seems you need to explain why the usual copying of properties (which is 100% supported and safe) wouldn't work for you.

Answer (score 0):

You could try constructor functions and turn an instance into something else.

Define both the Human and Zombie type that take a Human or Zombie as constructor parameter.

```
function Human(obj){
  obj = obj || {};
  this.legs = obj.legs === 0 ? 0 :
    obj.legs || 2;//defaults to 2
  this.name = obj.name || 'nameless';
  this.dead = false;
}
Human.prototype.saySomething = function(){
  console.log('Hello, I\'m ' + this.name);
};
//other functions of Human
function Zombie(obj){
  //Zombie is a Human but it's dead
  // re use Human constructor
  Human.call(this,obj);
  //re set the parameters that differ from Human
  this.dead = true;
  //add Zombie specific parameters if needed
}
//inherit prototype from Human
Zombie.prototype = Object.create(Human.prototype);
//repair constructor
Zombie.prototype.constructor=Zombie;
//override saySomething
Zombie.prototype.saySomething = function(){
  console.log('Huarrrghhh');
}

var ben = new Human({name:'ben'});
ben.saySomething();
console.log(ben);
// now ben becomes a Zombie
ben = new Zombie(ben);
ben.saySomething();
console.log(ben);
```

You could try different factory functions like so:

```
Human.toZombie = function(human){
  return new Zombie(human);
}
var ben = new Human();
ben = Human.toZombie(ben);
```

More on constructor functions and prototype: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16063711/1641941